# menu items disappear on hover (xwindows?)

Tags: linux-mint, graphics

i am not sure whether my problem is with xwindows, the desktop environment or something else completely. i am using linux mint 17.2 rafaela, i installed it a couple of weeks ago and my problem has been happening since the beginning. i tried switching the desktop environment, but it occurs no matter if i use cinammon or mate.
the problem is that when i hover on some menu items, all other items disappear, as illustrated on the screenshot:
[image: example]

this happens all the time in most applications. in some applications, for example skype, i cannot see anything except for the contour of the window - all buttons and menu items are invisible. other programs, like firefox, are functioning fine.

i would be grateful for some advice - at this point i don't even know what is causing the problem and how to search for a solution.